# Shortcut to launch REPL if no REPL running and send to REPL

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

I'd like to create a shortcut in sublime text that that does the following:

- if a REPL for R is open, send the selected text to this REPL
- else open a R REPL in a new window and send the text to this REPL.

I am using R-box. This package has  a python class  RboxSendTextCommand that uses the command repl_send

```
       external_id = self.view.scope_name(0).split(" ")[0].split(".", 1)[1] 
        self.view.window().run_command("repl_send", {"external_id": external_id, "text": cmd})
        return
```

This throws the error "Cannot find REPL for `r`" when no REPL is opened. I have tried to modify it in

```
        try:
            self.view.window().run_command("repl_send", {"external_id": external_id, "text": cmd})
        except:
            self.view.window().run_command("run_existing_window_command",{"id": "repl_r", "file": "config/R/Main.sublime-menu"})
            self.view.window().run_command("repl_send", {"external_id": external_id, "text": cmd})
            return
        else:
            self.view.window().run_command("repl_send", {"external_id": external_id, "text": cmd})
            return
```

However the same error happens when no REPL R window is open. Would you know how to do it? I  don't particular need to do that through the R-box script.

Comment: First of all, what's your OS? Secondly, would you please post your R-Box settings (R-Box.sublime-settings)?

Comment: Hello. I'm on OS10.9.4. By R-Box settings are "App": "SublimeREPL","auto_advance": true, "auto_completions": true. My code is really a long shot - the error "Cannot find REPL" is a Sublime Text one (ie a box appears with the error), not one within python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from SublimeREPL source code, if there is no REPL R running, it just print an error message. It won't throw any error. So `try...except...` won't work here.

```
class ReplSend(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, external_id, text, with_auto_postfix=True):
        for rv in manager.find_repl(external_id):
            ...
        else:
            sublime.error_message("Cannot find REPL for '{}'".format(external_id))
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do this. However, you can detect REPL R via its view name.

```
    if App == "SublimeREPL":
        external_id = self.view.scope_name(0).split(" ")[0].split(".", 1)[1]
        current_window = self.view.window()
        found = False
        repl_name = "*REPL* [%s]" % external_id
        for w in sublime.windows():
            for v in w.views():
                if v.name() == repl_name:
                    found = True
        if not found:
            current_window.run_command("run_existing_window_command",{"id": "repl_r", "file": "config/R/Main.sublime-menu"})
        current_window.run_command("repl_send", {"external_id": external_id, "text": cmd})
        return
```

Open REPL in a new window:

```
    sublime.run_command("new_window")
    created_window = sublime.active_window()
    created_window.run_command("run_existing_window_command",{"id": "repl_r", "file": "config/R/Main.sublime-menu"})
```

Comment: Yes I know it did not work because the error was just a sublime error box - but I had no idea what to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By any chance, would you know how to open this REPL window in a new window instead of a new tab (although I have the option `"open_files_in_new_window": false` for everything else)

Comment: You can use `sublime.run_command("new_window")` to create a new window and then open REPL in it.